# Simple routing of a controller results in ArgumentErrorr

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I have just created a controller using the command:

```
rails generate controller LegacyPlanCalculator index process
```

and then I added this to my routes.rb file:

```
match "legacy_plan_calculator" => "legacy_plan_calculator#index" 

match "/legacy_plan_calculator/process" => "legacy_plan_calculator#process"
```

I can see the controller and its views in the project. The actions in the controller are empty obviously:

```
class LegacyPlanCalculatorController < ApplicationController
  def index
  end

  def process
  end

end
```

But when I try to goto: `http://localhost:3000/legacy_plan_calculator` I get this error:

```
wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)

Rails.root: C:/Users/saadr/Dropbox/workspace/gps4money
```

I want to be able to land on the `index` view of the legacy plan calculator when the user puts in `localhost:3000/legacy_plan_calculator`

UPDATE: Here are the first few lines from 'Full Trace' on the error page:

```
actionpack (3.1.0) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:193:in `process'
actionpack (3.1.0) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:193:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.1.0) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:14:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.1.0) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:236:in `action'
actionpack (3.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:65:in `call'
actionpack (3.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:65:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:29:in `call'
```

And I don't know where these files are located so can't post relevant code from these files.

Comment: That's not a routing error. Please include first few lines of the stack trace after the error message, and the relevant code around the line number of the first file of your project in that stack trace.

Comment: I have added what you asked for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`process` is a [reserved word](http://oldwiki.rubyonrails.org/rails/pages/ReservedWords), just change it to any other and it will work.